# Getting mac adresses from arp request

Tags: python, arp

Hi i am trying to get a python script to get a mac address from a arp -n command and i am struggling to get just the mac address.

current code:

```
for ipaddr in uip:
 pid = Popen(["arp", "-n", ipaddr], stdout=PIPE)
 s = pid.communicate()[0]
 mac = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}\:){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", s) 
 print mac
```

uip is decleared at the begining of the script

current code out put

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9690>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9718>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9690>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9718>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9718> 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9690>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9718>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9690>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f18f0ea9718>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the captured results (that is, those captured by the parentheses). Those can be accesed by `mac.group` or `mac.groups` methods.

Instead of `print mac` you can use `print mac.group(0) if mac else "No result"`.

Comment: Thank you that worked. just have to wait 5 minuets for stack overflow to allow me to mark it as an answer